# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' pandas split

Tags: python, pandas, split

I tried to explode rows in a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
df2 = df.explode(split("priority", "/"))
```

and I have an error :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

It's just simple dataframe (datatypes: object):

| Ticket | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1/P2 |
| 2 | P3/P4 |

I need to have:

| Ticket | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 1 | P2 |
| 2 | P3 |
| 2 | P4 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `assign()` and `explode()`:

```
df=df.assign(Priority=df['Priority'].str.split('/')).explode('Priority',ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

```
df['Priority']=df['Priority'].str.split('/')
df=df.explode('Priority',ignore_index=True)
```